# toggler icon in bootstrap 4 is coming in the middle on mobile screen?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created navbar in bootstrap 4 but the toggler icon coming in middle when it open on mobile screen as it is on right side by defualt, is there any error or missing class please help I'm not able to resolve
there is code pen link
https://codepen.io/mujtaba803/pen/BaQEbmd

my coding is here

```
<nav class="navbar-nav navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a href="" class="navbar-brand"><img src="logo.jpg" alt=""></a>
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
    data-toggle="collapse" data- target="#myMenu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myMenu">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Courses</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: In your code snippet above, on the first line in the `<nav>` tag, instead of the class `navbar-nav` try just `navbar`

Comment: Yep. Make sure you're following the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/) correctly. That class is for dropdown components.